# Hide p elements

Tags: jquery

I have a selection and when I click on the selection the data will be appear in the `table id="tbl"`.

I would like to hide the table when the data did not exist in the database and make the p tag appear. However if I structure my code like this, the second time I click on the option with no value the text `There is no record found did not appear` can anyone help?

```
function Report_response(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.Elem1 != null) {
        $('#elem1').html(data.Elem1);
        $('#elem2').html(data.Elem2);
        $('#elem3').html(data.Elem3);
        $('#elem4').html(data.Elem4);
        $('#tbl').css("display", "");
        $('#noDataMsg').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#tbl').css("display", "none");
        $('#noDataMsg').text("There is no record found");
    }
```

Comment: I think it’s because you don’t `show()` `#noDataMsg` in your `else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#noDataMsg` is hidden but you're only assigning it's value through text() method and you didn't show that. Just show that:

```
else{
   $('#tbl').css("display","none");
   $('#noDataMsg').text("There is no record found");
   $('#noDataMsg').show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maintain a counter whenever data is inserted.
if deleted decrease the counter to conter--
if counter is 0,use jquery hide().